# Can I use standard child documents across multiple masters

Tags: lyx

I have a number of standard documents which are designed to be reusable in assembling larger documents. This doesn't seem to work in Lyx - if I set up two masters and include one child  document in both, the section numbering goes haywire. I'd like to to determine if this is a bug, user error or functional restriction. Any help appreciated. (Lyx 2.0.4).

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If you post a MWE (minimum working example) showing your problem you're more likely to get help.

Comment: LyX's child documents are supposed to have only one master document. Does it work if you only have one master document open at a time?